# Capacitor iOS app receiving ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage rejection?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, capacitor

I've created a web app using React and Capacitor to build for iOS and Android.

Android works fine and I've been able to submit to the Play Store without issue. However upon submitting my iOS version to Apple, I received an email explaining that my app is using a deprecated API: UIWebView and it should be using WKWebView instead.

Upon further investigation though, I've found references ([here](https://ionicframework.com/blog/understanding-itms-90809-uiwebview-api-deprecation/) and [here](https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/pull/1925)) to the fact that as of version 1.2.0, Capacitor has removed references to UIWebView.

I'm using version 2.1.2 of Capacitor core, cli, and iOS. So I'm confused as to why I'm still receiving this error.

Ultimately, does anyone know how to proceed with debugging this?

All the best.

PS not sure if it helps, but this is my package.json dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@capacitor/android": "^2.1.2",
    "@capacitor/cli": "^2.1.2",
    "@capacitor/core": "^2.1.2",
    "@capacitor/ios": "^2.1.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "capacitor-admob-advanced": "^1.4.1",
    "capacitor-firebase-auth": "^0.3.1",
    "firebase": "^7.14.1",
    "firebase-admin": "^8.11.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.6.1",
    "html-react-parser": "^0.10.3",
    "jetifier": "^1.6.5",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-flip-page": "^1.6.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
    "react-select": "^3.1.0",
    "react-swipeable-routes": "^0.8.0",
    "react-swipeable-views": "^0.13.9",
    "react-swipeable-views-utils": "^0.13.9",
    "react-textarea-autosize": "^7.1.2"
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s capacitor-firebase-auth, you have to update to 2.0.0 or newer

https://github.com/baumblatt/capacitor-firebase-auth/issues/89